# Using std::copy_if write number to file, can't get correct result

Tags: c++

Summary & My understanding:

My question can be referred to "using a istream_iterator twice with a same ifstream", which is not a good idea because after the first traversing, the stream is already reached the (end-of-file). Since we use `istream_iterator` to traverse the whole stream:

1. Because `istream_iterator` is a single-pass iterator, so we can't go
   back to reload the stream again.
2. Because the stream is already reached the end-of-file, even we bind a new iterator to it, the iterator still points the end-of-file.

Thanks those ppl who answered my questions!

====================

Update：

I just did some sample test:

1. with two different `ifstream` objects, the result is correct.
2. with two different `istream_iterator` which bind to the same `ifstream` obejct, the result is not correct; instead of nothing in file, I got number `2` there.

Just like @aschepler 's answer below, `istream_iterator` is a single-pass iterator and will invalid after it did the self-increment; but how a brand new iterator still not work for this? Why I have to create two different `ifstream` objects to make the program work?

Thanks for your answers!

===================Original Question Here==========================

I have a question about a exercise 10.33 on C++ primer 5th (p.407). My problem was occurred at this portion:

> using ostream_iterators, write the odd numbers into the first output file, and Write the even numbers into the second file.

Some defination here:

```
ifstream ifs(argv[1]);
istream_iterator<int> int_in(ifs);
istream_iterator<int> int_in_eof;

ofstream ofs_odd(argv[2]);
ofstream ofs_even(argv[3]);

ostream_iterator<int> int_out_odd(ofs_odd, " ");
ostream_iterator<int> int_out_even(ofs_even, " ");
```

Actually std::for_each did a good job:

```
for_each(int_in, int_in_eof, [&int_out_odd, &int_out_even](const int i)
                            { *(i & 0X1 ? int_out_odd : int_out_even)++ = i; });
```

The correct result looks like this:

```
input file: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
output_odd: 1 3 5 6 9
output_even: 2 4 6 8
```

Then I tried to use copy_if to implement:

```
//copy odd number to odd file
copy_if(int_in, int_in_eof, int_out_odd, [](const int i)
                            {return i & 0X1; });
//copy even number to even file
copy_if(int_in, int_in_eof, int_out_even, [](const int i)
                            {return ！(i & 0X1); });
```

The result looks like this:

```
input file: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
output_odd: 1 3 5 6 9
output_even:
```

I got nothing inside even file.

My question is the first copy_if changing anything inside the istream ?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I think the best practice would be to create a container to hold these values and then do subsequent traversals on that, e.g., `vector<int> input_values(istream_iterator<int>(ifs), istream_iterator<int>());`  Otherwise, you would need to reopen the entire file again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`istream_iterator` is a single-pass iterator, not a ForwardIterator.  After you do `++iter`, an old copy of `iter` is invalid.

Comment: thanks for your answer. So my understanding is, if I insist on using `copy_if`, I need to create two different `istream_iterator` right? or I have to create two different `ifstream object` instead?